# Box counting method for fractal dimension

Tags: fractals

First I saw [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension) that the box counting fractal dimension defined by

> $D = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}{ {\log N( \epsilon)} \over {\log { {1}\over{ \epsilon }}}}$

which makes sense for me. Then I saw [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13125/measuring-fractal-dimension-of-natural-objects-from-digital-images#) a mathematica code for calculating it. This method does a  fitting of the data $ \{ x= \log { {1}\over{ \epsilon }}, y=  \log N( \epsilon) \}$ to a line, giving two parameter $a$ and $b$ such that

> $ y = a   x + b $

and $a$ is interpreted as the box counting fractal dimension, which I don't understand because I don't think there is any reason to assume linear behaviour.

However, this method is "correct", because

> ${{y} \over {x}} = a + {{b}\over{x}}  \quad $ and $ \quad \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}$

but by the same reason there are infinite other "correct" methods assuming

> $ y = a  x + b + {{c} \over {x}} + {{d} \over {x^2}} + ... $

or other more complicated things.

**Why do [they](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13125/measuring-fractal-dimension-of-natural-objects-from-digital-images#) choose a linear behaviour? (Instead of just plotting** ${ {\log N( \epsilon)} \over {\log { {1}\over{ \epsilon }}}}$ **against** $\epsilon$  **and taking the** $y$**-intercept)**

Comment: The limit is really only defined for mathematically idealized objects. For *real* objects, we should look at a sufficiently wide range of scales, from very zoomed out up to very zoomed in, and compute the dimension at each one. A shape is considered to be fractal only when the measured dimension stays approximately constant across multiple scales. The slope computation accomplishes just that. This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gB9n2gHsHN4) describes the situation nicely.

Comment: Precisely in that video it is noticed how slow the fractal dimension converges when calculated that way. The value $a$ in my question (the order of the polynomial in the video), only approaches the fractal dimension when $x \rightarrow 0$ (when the scaling factor goes to infinity in the video). So why not just take the _computational_ or _approximate_ limit?

Comment: It's been a few years but I stumbled back upon this question for some reason. When I did so, I realized that my response ignored the important question of *regularity* of fractals, which I think is really the central issue here. So I've updated the answer some.

Answer (score 7):

Like Euclidean objects, fractals are idealized abstractions of reality. A tree is not a fractal any more than its trunk is a line segment. As a result, we cannot compute an actual limit to find the box-counting dimension of an object. Even an attempt to approximate the limit by using a small value of $\varepsilon$ in
$$\frac{\log(N({\varepsilon}))}{\log(1/\varepsilon)}$$
is hazardous because we don't know a priori what scale of $\varepsilon$ works well with the object.

Now, if we'd like to do mathematical analysis of an idealized fractal (compute its dimension, for example), then one desirable property is *regularity*. More specifically, we might hope that the relationship
$$N_{\varepsilon} \approx 1/\varepsilon^{\text{dim}}$$
is maintained over a wide range of small scales. The process of fitting a line to the data
$$\{ x= \log { {1}/ \varepsilon_k}, y=  \log N( \epsilon_k) \}$$
for some terms chosen from a sequence $\varepsilon_k$ that tends down to zero allows us to estimate the dimension in a way that accounts for exactly that regularity.

As it turns out, we can also show by example that this slope-fitting technique can work better than just computing
$$\frac{\log(N({\varepsilon}))}{\log(1/\varepsilon)}$$
for a small value of $\varepsilon$. Let's generate such an example
with Mathematica, since this question was originally posted on [mathematica.stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com).

Consider the following image of the Sierpinski carpet:

```
Import[
  "https://www.marksmath.org/FractalGeometryPackages/FractalGeometry/IteratedFunctionSystems.m"
];
A = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}/3;
IFS = {A, #} & /@ {
    {-1, 1}, {0, 1},  {1, 1},
    {-1, 0},          {1, 0},
    {-1, -1}, {0, -1},{1, -1}
    };
sierpPic = ShowIFS[IFS, 5, PlotRange -> All,
  Initiator -> Polygon[{{-3, -3}, {3, -3}, {3, 3}, {-3, 3}}/2],
  PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

Here's an easy way to box-count the image:

```
pic = Binarize[ImportString[ExportString[sierpPic, "PNG",
     ImageSize -> 2^10]]];
data = ImageData[pic];
test[matrix_] := Boole[Length[Cases[matrix, 0, {2}, 1]] > 0];
count[n_] := Total[Flatten[Map[test, Partition[data, {n, n}], {2}]]];
radii = Table[2^k, {k, 0, 8}];
counts = Table[count[r], {r, radii}]

(* Out: 
  {626688, 167476, 45276, 12124, 3287, 864, 236, 60, 16}
*)
```

Here's the "approximate limit" computation:

```
Log[First[counts]]/Log[2^10] // N

(* Out: 1.92574 *)
```

Here's a slope fit computation:

```
Fit[Transpose[Log[{1/radii[[2 ;; -3]], counts[[2 ;; -3]]}]], {1, x}, x]

(* Out: 13.3465 + 1.89636 x *)
```

The actual dimension is
$$\frac{\log(8)}{\log(3)} \approx 1.89279.$$
Thus, this choice of slope fitting does a better job.

Now, I freely admit that I fiddled a bit with the choice of points to use in my fit of the slope. The point, though, is that slope fitting can do a better job. Also, it's easy to see why the "approximate limit" approach might fail. If $\varepsilon$ is too small, the small blocks in the approximate Sierpinski carpet are solid and contribute too much to the box-count. Thus, we get too large a value. That's exactly the point when it comes to a real world object. An apparent, approximate self-similar structure is only valid down to some scale and you have no way of knowing how far down you should look.

Ultimately, though, box-counting with natural objects is necessarily approximate, error prone, and not necessarily even well defined.

---

I've also implemented this same technique in:

- Python, as shown in [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050990/) and
- Javascript, in [this Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@mcmcclur/box-counting-dimension-examples).